# Kotlin - Filtering collections by sub-type or generic type

Tags: kotlin

Before I start, I'm using Kotlin 1.2 which may be important in understanding this problem. If I remember correctly there are some bugs with the way Kotlin 1.2 handles generics, which were fixed in subsequent versions.

I have the following type hierarchy, designed to hold individual settings in a configuration:

```kotlin
open class Setting<T : Any>(val property: String, val value: T) {
    val normalizedProperty: String get() = property.toUpperCase()
}

open class StringSetting(property: String, value: String) : Setting<String>(property, value) {
    val normalizedValue: String get() = value.toUpperCase()
}

class Role(value: String) : StringSetting("Role", value)
class Permission(value: String) : StringSetting("Permission", value)
```

Now say that I want to use some of these types to create a configuration:

```kotlin
private val settings: Iterable<Setting<*>> = listOf(
    Setting("a", 123),
    Setting("b", 456),
    Setting("c", "Hello, World!"),
    Setting("d", true),
    Setting("e", false),
    StringSetting("f", "abc"),
    StringSetting("g", "xyz"),
    Role("Admin"),
    Role("Guest"),
    Permission("CAN_DO_THIS"),
    Permission("CAN_DO_THAT")
)
```

Now I have an extension function which I want to be able to use to filter the collection by the type of setting:

```kotlin
fun <V, S : Setting<V>> Iterable<Setting<*>>.filterByType(
    settingType: Class<S>, 
    valueType: Class<V>? = null
) : List<S> { ... }
```

A few things to note:

- I didn't include this functions implementation because the signature itself doesn't work.
- `valueType` is marked nullable and defaults to `null` because for derived types, the value type does not need to be specified (unless the derived type was itself also generic).

When using the function, these calls work...

```kotlin
val roles = settings.filterByType(Role::class.java)
val strings = settings.filterByType(StringSetting::class.java)
val permissions = settings.filterByType(Permission::class.java)
```

...but these don't...

```kotlin
val settingsOfAnyType = settings.filterByType(Setting::class.java)
// Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V

val settingsOfAnyType = settings.filterByType(Setting::class.java, Any::class.java)
// Type parameter bound for S in <fn signature> is not satisfied: inferred type Setting<*> is not a subtype of Setting<Any>
```

Is this simply a limitation of Kotlin 1.2, or is there something I need to do to my function signature? Any suggestions welcome!

Note: I *could* just do this with a Kotlin inline function...

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Setting<*>> Iterable<Setting<*>>.filterByType(): List<T> { ... }
```

...but what about our friends in the Java world?

Comment: Will it work if you declare it with the following signature `fun <V, S : Setting<in V> Iterable<Setting<*>>.filterByType(settingType: Class<S>, valueType: Class<in V>? = null)`?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь Yes, that seems to work, although the resulting type is `List<Setting<*>>` in all cases.